# Piping the same output through one or several grep commands on condition

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I am currently writing a bash script to modify the output of my LaTeX compilations to have only what I find relevant printing on the console. As I would like this script to be extremely thorough, I set up different options to toggle different output filters at the same time depending of the nature of the informations given through the compilation (Fatal error, warning, over/underfull h/vbox...).

For those who may not know, we often need to perform several compilations in a row to have a full LaTeX document with correct labels, page numbering, index, table of contents... + other commands like `bibtex` or `makeglossaries` for bibliography and, well, glossaries. I therefore have a loop that execute everything and stops if there is a fatal error encountered, but **should** continue if it is only a minor warning.

My main command line is piping the `pdflatex` output through a reversed `grep` that finds errors line (starting by `!`). Like this, the script stops only if `grep` found a fatal error.

```
: | pdflatex --halt-on-error $@ | { ! grep --color=auto '^!.*' -A200; }
```

But when I activate any other filters (eg. `'*.full.*'` for over/underfull lines), I need to be able to continue compiling to be able to identify it there is a major necessity to correct it (hey, sometimes, underfull lines are just not *that* ugly...).

That means my `grep` command cannot be inverted as in the first line, and I cannot (or don't know how to) use the same `grep` with a different regex. notice that if if using a different `grep`, it should also be read from the `pdflatex` output and I cannot pipe it directly following the above snippet.

To sum up, it should roughly look like this :

```
   pdflatex --> grep for fatal errors --> if more filters, grep for those filters
   --> pass to next step
```

I came up with several attempts that did not work properly :

This one works only if I want to compile WITH the warnings. Looking only for errors does not work.

```
latex_compilation() {
: | pdflatex --halt-on-error $@ | tee >({ ! grep --color=auto '^!.*' -A200; }) >({ grep --color=auto "$warnings_filter" -A5 };) >/dev/null
}


latex_compilation() {
: | pdflatex --halt-on-error $@ | tee >({ ! grep --color=auto '^!.*' -A200; }) >/dev/null | ({ grep --color=auto "$warnings_filter" -A5 };)
}
```

or even desperately

```
latex_compilation() {
: | pdflatex --halt-on-error $@ |
if [[ "$warnings_on" = true ]]; then
    { grep --color=auto "$warnings_filter" -A5 };
fi
{ ! grep --color=auto '^!.*' -A200; }
}
```

This one would work but uses 2 compilation processes for each step (you could easily go up to 7/8 compilations steps for a big and complex document). It should be avoided if possible.

```
latex_compilation() {
if [[ "$warnings_on" = true ]]; then
    : | pdflatex --halt-on-error $@ | \
    { grep --color=auto "$warnings_filter" -A5 };
fi
: | pdflatex --halt-on-error $@ | \
{ ! grep --color=auto '^!.*' -A200; }
}
```

I spent hours looking for solutions online, but didn't find any yet.
I really hope this is clear enough because it is a mess to sum up, moreover writing it. You can find the relavant code [here](https://pastebin.com/xNbBi7ze) if needed for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This one would work but uses 2 compilation processes

So let's use one.

```
latex_compilation() {
   local tmp
   tmp=$(pdflatext ... <&-)
   if [[ "$warnings_on" = true ]]; then
       grep --color=auto "$warnings_filter" -A5 <<<"$tmp"
   fi
   ! grep --color=auto '^!.*' -A200 <<<"$tmp"
}
```

Or you can do that asynchronously, by parsing the output, in your chosem programmign langauge. For Bash see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 :

```
line_is_warning() { .... }
latex_compilation() {
   local outputlines=0 failed
   while IFS= read -r line; do
       if "$warnings_on" && line_is_warning "$line"; do
           outputlines=5  # will output 5 lines after
       fi
       if [[ "$line" =~ ^! ]]; then
           failed=1
           outputlines=200 # will output 200 lines after
       fi
       if ((outputlines != 0)); then
           ((outputlines--))
           printf "%s\n" "$line"
       fi
   done < <(pdflatext ... <&-)
   if ((failed)); then return 1; fi
}
```

But Bash will be extremely slow. Consider using AWK or Python or Perl.

> looking for solutions online

Exactly, you have to write a solution yourself, for your specific requirements.

> his one works only if I want to compile WITH the warnings. Looking only for errors does not work.

You can write whole code blocks inside `>( ... )` and basically anywhere. The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of rightmost command (except `set -o pipefail`). Put the failing command as the rightmost of the pipeline.

```
latex_compilation() {
    pdflatex --halt-on-error "$@" <&- |
    tee >(
       if "$warnings_on"; then
         grep --color=auto "$warnings_filter" -A5
       else
          cat >/dev/null
       fi
    ) |
    ! grep --color=auto '^!.*' -A200
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does the job perfectly. I wasn't too far but definitely missing something here. For now, process time is not a problem, but I will give Perl & awk a look.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to use `awk` filtering pattern.

Read more about `awk` filtering pattern [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Patterns-and-Actions).

With `awk` you can create complex filtering patterns logic: `!`=not, `&&`=and, `||`=or.

For example if you have 3 filtering RegExp patterns: `Pattern_1`, `Pattern_2`, `Pattern 3`.

#### Example 1

You can make a combined filter all 3 patterns in the following command:

```
awk '/Pattern_1/ && /Pattern_2/ && /Pattern_3/ 1' scanned_file1 scanned_file2 ...
```

The result will be printing only lines that match all 3 pattern.

#### Example 2

You can make a combined inverse filter all 3 pattern in the following command:

```
awk '!/Pattern_1/ && !/Pattern_2/ && !/Pattern_3/ 1' scanned_file1 scanned_file2 ...
```

The result will be printing lines not matching any of the 3 patterns.

#### Example 3

You can make a combined inverse filter `Pattern_1` and match `Pattern_2` or `Pattern_3`:

```
awk '!/Pattern_1/ && (/Pattern_2/ || /Pattern_3/)' scanned_file1 scanned_file2 ...
```

The result will be printing lines not matching `Pattern_1` but match `Pattern_2` or `Pattern_3`.